# Android Selectors Text Color

Tags: android, button, colors

I've been over way too many StackOverflow questions and still can't get it working.

I dynamically (programmatically) create a number of buttons on my activity. I need to use selectors to change the background and text color depending on if the button is pressed or not.

I've got the background to change from black to white when its pressed, but I can't seem to get the text color to change (or set it for that matter ) - it just defaults to black.

Here's what I've got.

Java file:

```
monthButtons[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background);
monthButtons[i].setTextColor(R.color.text_color);
```

button_background.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/white"/>

    <item android:drawable="@color/black"/>        
</selector>
```

text_color.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
    <item
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
 </selector>
```

Can someone point me to a method to change the text color when the button is pressed? Please bear in mind I don't have anything defined in a layout file for these buttons.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use one background xml? Like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@color/white"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<item android:drawable="@color/black"
      android:textColor="@color/white"/>        
</selector>//Untested
```

And set it to be background for the button. If it doesn't work you can always do it programmatically. Hope this helps.

How about this:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
    {
        button.setBackground("#000");
        edittext.setTextColor("#dedede");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        button.setBackground("#dedede");
        edittext.setTextColor("#000");
        return true;
    }
 return false;
})); // Untested. Sorry i'm away from pc :(
```

Comment: Ok, it worked with the onTouchListener. Been using the onClickListener for the other events. Thanks.

Comment: textColor doesn't change for me. Are you sure this works properly?

Comment: not work. use two selector for background and text color , works

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Color State List Resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)** to change the text color dynamically:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html